# Publishing and hosting Web API developed in .net core through IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, publish

I have WEB API developed in .net core (VS 2017). I need to deploy this api in IIS. This is the procedure I have followed.

1. Open VS 2017, open the project -> right click on API , click on Publish.
2. Selected File System -> Give a path where binaries where to be placed-> Click on Publish button.

After it is finished, there are some files in the physical path. I have copied the files on to the server where it is supposed to be hosted.

In the server, this is what I have done:

1. Installed .Net core run time.
2. Opened IIS , right click on default website -> Add Application -> Give name of application (say ABC) -> give physical path (where binaries are copied)-> Click OK.

There is a simple Get method in the API for now, where it just returns a string.

Say if the IP address of the server is 10.1.1.1 , this is the URL I'm using.

http://10.1.1.1/ABC/api/GetData

I'm trying this through Postman. I'm getting 500 Internal server error.

When I follow the same process for Web API developed in .Net framework, it is working perfectly fine.

Is there any step which I'm missing for .net core?

Comment: Well, it's hard because it could be multiple things.. I guess a good start is asking if you took a look (and followed) at this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure the following:

1. .NET core hosting bundle is installed on the server
2. Your application pool .NET CLR version is set to “No Managed Code”

For details check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2